# Is this the right way to use MVVM structure with ViewModel and RecyclerView without any issues?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

So I have an activity containing 2 fragments, a repository and a ViewModel class since I'm following android developers' guide to use a MVVM structure. So far it seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm following a good practices when it comes to the implementation. So far it looks like this:

Repository class:

```
public class MyRepository{

...
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Book>> bookList;

    public MyRepository(){
        bookList= new MutableLiveData<>();
        getBookList(); //method that uses retrofit to fill bookList, since it's empty at this point       

    }
...
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class BookViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MyRepository repository;
    private LiveData<ArrayList<Book>> bookList;

    public void init(){
        repository = new MyRepository();
        bookList = repository.getBookList();
    };

    public LiveData<ArrayList<Book>>  getBookList() {
            if (bookList== null) {
                bookList= new MutableLiveData<>();
            }
        return bookList;
    }
```

Recycler view that shows the book list:

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerView.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Book> bookList;

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        context = context;
        bookList =  new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Book> list){
        bookList= list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
...
}
```

Fragment 1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
....
     @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {

        ....

        recyclerview_adapter = new AdapterRecyclerView(Context);
        myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((getActivity())));
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerview_adapter);

      viewModel.getbookList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<Producto>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<Producto> books) { 
                    recyclerview_adapter.setList(viewModel.getbookList().getValue());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

...
}
```

Questions:

1) Am I using this correctly? Should I use the viewModel object in onActivityCreated() or elsewhere to prevent any errors?

2) Should I use an instance of the viewModel in each fragment, or should I use it in the activity that contains them all, and then pass it to each fragment by parameters?

3) Where is the correct place to call `init()` (method to get all the books in the database) for the first time, so the user sees the book list stored in the database when the app is opened?

4) Should the `ArrayList<Book> bookList;` in `MyRecyclerView` class be a LiveData/MutableData as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe the viewModel in `onViewCreated` in Fragment.

**Reason** -> your are updating UI when changes in the Viewmodel occur. You might encouter a crash if you populate the view with data from viewmodel if view element is not yet instantiated.

2. Better have a separate instance of viewmodel for each fragment.

**Reason** -> If you have only one instance of viewmodel in activity, passing them to fragments will not be ideal as it will get complex when you add more fragments.

3. `Init` can be called from different places depending on the type of tasks it performs. In your case, onViewCreated should be good.

**reason**-> In your case, your `init` is fetching data from repository.Once that data is fetched, your `recyclerview` will come into play. You dont want to play with view elements in `OnCreateView`

4. `ArrayList<Book> bookList` in `RecyclerView` does not have to be livedata.

**Reason**-> Livedata is for communication between view (Activity/Fragment) and Viewmodel. Once your livedata has been observed by the view, you dont need to treat it as livedata anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Regarding (1), I read about fragments lifecycles and creating an observer in the `onCreate()` method: apparently when the fragment is destroyed or recovered from the backstack, it disappears but the observer instance remains, so for the observer the fragment is still the same, it doesn't update and the layout stays empty. To prevent this, I read observers should be put in `onCreatedView()` or in `onActivityCreated()`, since at that point we can ensure that `getActivity()` won't be null. Will placing it where you suggest solve this as well?

Comment: you can initialize Viewmodel in onCreate. But You would be observing on onViewCreated anyways. So yes, it will solve the issue.